# SharePoint 2013 - Content Search

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-type

I have a SharePoint Document Library (Subsite) there I have columns. I want to display specific columns on another website and at the same link to the document.

I know that it can use the content search. How can you pass this columns to the content search?

I saw the refinable strings can this be the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every column that gets indexed by the Search Service Application (SSA) has a Crawled Property created for it. When you go into the SSA via Central Administration and look at the Search Schema, you should be able to dig up the Crawled Property (usually prefixed with 'ows_').

You can then create a Managed Property--mapped to the Crawled Property--which will become available to use after the next crawl. You can then reference the Managed Property for use as a filter/refiner, or in a Display Template.

If your websites aren't on the same farm/sharing the same SSA, then you'll need to configure the SSA at the receiving end and ensure it's crawling your content.

Comment: Thanks fpr your answers! @Surly your right, I had done a implementation like this, but I did not realy remember on it. But this must be the way it works. So my problem is that one of the colums is working fine, I get the infos, but for another column in the Doc Library it doesnt work (Problem is there, that it is a research/ lookup column), so the lookup column is not shown in the content search

Answer (score 0):

You can use Content Search web part and custom display template to display the columns you want.

So I would copy one of the item display templates and rename it and change its title. 
Add the column to the Header section (maybe you will need to map the crawled property to one of the refinablexxx field)

Give it a shot!